# Getting arraylist char items returning into a string I can use to printout

Tags: java, arraylist

I got an arraylist made containing two letters and one number. I need to display it like for example "ab1". But everytime I get a printline with some arraylist code: "pp4main.Letter@f7e6a96pp4"

This is my array list: `ArrayList<Letter> letterlijst = new ArrayList<Letter>();`

My code trying to display:

```
public Kofferslot(char letter1, char letter2, int cijfer){

    Letter letterlijst1 = new Letter();
    letterlijst1.setLetter(letter1);
    Letter letterlijst2 = new Letter();
    letterlijst1.setLetter(letter2);

    letterlijst.add(letterlijst1);
    letterlijst.add(letterlijst2);


    Cijfer cijfer3 = new Cijfer();
    cijfer3.setCijfer(cijfer);

    String letterstring1 = letterlijst.get(0).toString();
    String letterstring2 = letterlijst.get(1).toString();

    System.out.println(letterstring1 + letterstring2 + cijfer3);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override `toString()` in your Letter class, By default Object's toString() will be invoked

```
 @override
 public String toString() {
       return ""+ch1+ch2+number
  }
```

Where ch1, ch2 are the char attributes in your Letter class and number is an int attribute

Answer (score 1):

You have to override your `toString()` method of the `Letter` and `Cijfer` class.

Something like this:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return String.valueOf(mijnLetter);
}
```

---

But a nicer approach would be to a getter (`getLetter()`), instead of the toString.

Answer (score 1):

you have to either override the toString() to print the letter or instead of using :

```
letterlijst.get(0)
```

use something like this :

```
letterlijst.get(0).getLetter() // return letter1 of setLetter(letter1)
```